# 'ul >li' like dropdown + filtering by class

Tags: jquery, filter, drop-down-menu

I wrote small function ( actually 2).
First, ul > li list like a custom dropdown + filter at the same time.

What it does:

```
- when selected an 'li'
- copy span from inside of it to - > 'a href' (top of the dropdown)
- get class of the span inside 'a href' - which we just copied
- hide all div's which does not have selected class (div's and span's have same classes)
```

And all worked fine till I have added 'all' option with if else conditions.

Chrome js console is saying that selected classes in undefined when is last step

```
$('.content div').not('.' + CheckWhichClassSelected).hide();
```

**What I'm doing wrong?**

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/hLcML/

HTML

```
<div class="filter">
    <a class="dropDownSelect" href="#"> -- select -- </a>
    <ul class="dropDownList">
        <li><span class="filter0">All</span></li>
        <li><span class="filter1">Filter 1</span></li>
        <li><span class="filter2">Filter 2</span></li>
        <li><span class="filter3">Filter 3</span></li>
        <li><span class="filter4">Filter 4</span></li>
    </ul>

</div>    
<div class="tab-menu">
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="filter1">1</div>
    <div class="filter2">2</div>
    <div class="filter3">3</div>
    <div class="filter4">4</div>
    <div class="filter1">1</div>
    <div class="filter2">2</div>
    <div class="filter3">3</div>
    <div class="filter4">4</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
/*!  OnLoad 
---------------------------------------------*/
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.dropDownSelect').click(function(event) {
        $(this).next().slideToggle(100);
    });

    $('.dropDownList li').click(function(event) {
        $(this).parent().slideUp(100);
        $('.dropDownSelect').empty();
        $(this).children().clone().appendTo('.dropDownSelect');

        // ShowSelectedClass
        var CheckWhichClassSelected = $('.dropDownSelect').children().attr('class');
        alert(CheckWhichClassSelected);

        $('.content div').show();
        if (CheckWhichClassSelected === filter0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('.content div').not('.' + CheckWhichClassSelected).hide();
        }


    });


});
```

**Any help much appreciated.**

Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed two apex here:

```
   if (CheckWhichClassSelected === filter0) {
```

it should be:

```
  if (CheckWhichClassSelected === 'filter0') {
```

Now it seems to work ok:

http://jsfiddle.net/hLcML/8/

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap `filter0` in `if (CheckWhichClassSelected === filter0) {` inside quotation marks:

`if (CheckWhichClassSelected === "filter0") {`

working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/WmP3P/